# Styling of Samsung Galaxy S3 overflow menu pressed state

Tags: android, android-layout

Does someone know how to style the Samsung Galaxy S3 overflow menu when pressed? I know that I can style the menu itself when adding the following attribute to my theme:

```
<item name="android:panelBackground">@drawable/menu_hardkey_panel</item>
```

This works for the background but when pressed it shows the blue holo glow which I want to change to a different color.